# Joining 4 separate tables with count()

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL and i've been stuck with this problem.
I have 4 tables. I've filled them with some mock information.

```
Games Table
|ID |Name      |Price |
|---|----------|------|
|1  |TestGame1 |2500  |
|2  |TestGame2 |1500  |
|3  |TestGame3 |3500  |

User Table
|ID |Username |Email               |
|---|---------|--------------------|
|1  |TestUser1|testEmail1@email.com|
|2  |TestUser2|testEmail2@email.com|
|3  |TestUser3|testEmail3@email.com|

UserOwnsGame Table
|GameID |UserID |
|-------|-------|
|1      |1      |
|2      |2      |
|1      |2      |
|3      |1      |
|2      |1      |

Review Table
|GameID |UserID |Rating |Comment                          |LastEdit  |
|-------|-------|-------|---------------------------------|----------|
|1      |1      |5.0    |I love this game                 |2022-04-19|
|1      |2      |4.5    |Came short of a 5.0              |2022-04-19|
|2      |2      |2.7    |Above average but nothing special|2022-04-19|
```

I want to scan through the data on all tables using a single query and get a table like the following,

| GameID | UserID | Username | UserReviewCount | UserGameCount | Rating | Comment | LastEdit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | TestUser1 | 2 | 3 | 5.0 | I love this game | 2022-04-19 |
| 1 | 2 | TestUser1 | 1 | 2 | 4.5 | Came short of a 5.0 | 2022-04-19 |
| 2 | 2 | TestUser2 | 1 | 2 | 2.7 | Above average but nothing special | 2022-04-19 |

I want it for all reviews in the review table. I've tried multiple times. I can figure out ways to get the data on seperate queries. I can't figure out how to combine it all into one table like this. Especially considering the count().

Here;

- UserReviewCount - Number of reviews user has made. Count on Review table.
- UserGameCount - Number of games user owns. Count on UserOwnsGame table.

I've been stuck on this for one or two days now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What version of mySQL are you using?  run `select version();` - window functions would be useful and are avaliable from version 8

Comment: @Kendle It seems im currently running 8.0.28

Comment: Could you please make sure the data you provided is correct? It seems not. If I just do a select like this, the result does not match your data (and this is not just why I renamed your critical tables/columns "user" to "username" and "comment" to "rcomment") : SELECT *
FROM games g 
JOIN userownsgame ug ON g.id = ug.gameID
JOIN usernames u ON u.id = ug.usernameid
JOIN review r ON r.gameID = g.id and r.usernameID = u.id
GROUP BY g.id, u.id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a sub-query to count the number of games owned. We could have used another sub-query to count the number of reviews but, as we are already using the table, it is easier to use the window function count() over.

```
create table Games(ID int,Name varchar(10),Price int);
insert into Games values(1,'TestGame1',2500  ),(2,'TestGame2',1500  ),(3,'TestGame3',3500  );
create table Users (ID int, Username varchar(10),Email varchar(25));
insert into Users values(1,'TestUser1','testEmail1@email.com'),(2,'TestUser2','testEmail2@email.com'),(3,'TestUser3','testEmail3@email.com');
create table UserOwnsGame (GameID int, UserID int);
insert into UserOwnsGame values(1,1),(2,2),(1,2),(3,1),(2,1);
create table Review (GameID int,UserID int,Rating decimal(3,2),Comment varchar(50),LastEdit  date);
insert into Review values(1,1,5.0,'I love this game','2022-04-19'),(1,2,4.5,'Came short of a 5.0','2022-04-19'),(2,2,2.7,'Above average but nothing special','2022-04-19');
```

```
select 
  r.GameID,
  u.ID,
  u.Username,
  count(r.GameID) over (partition by r.UserID)
    as UserReviewCount,
  uog.number_games UserGamescount,
  r.Rating,
  r.Comment,
  r.LastEdit
from
Users u
join Review r 
on u.ID = r.UserID
join (select UserID,count(GameID) number_games
      from UserOwnsGame
      group by UserID) uog
on u.ID = uog.UserID;
```

> ```
> GameID | ID | Username  | UserReviewCount | UserGamescount | Rating | Comment                           | LastEdit  
> -----: | -: | :-------- | --------------: | -------------: | -----: | :-------------------------------- | :---------
>      1 |  1 | TestUser1 |               1 |              3 |   5.00 | I love this game                  | 2022-04-19
>      1 |  2 | TestUser2 |               2 |              2 |   4.50 | Came short of a 5.0               | 2022-04-19
>      2 |  2 | TestUser2 |               2 |              2 |   2.70 | Above average but nothing special | 2022-04-19
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71d26ae84f704a3d365143729dbf0570)*

Comment: Thanks, I also think this is a good way. And it's good you named the table "users" instead of "user". But I think you should also rename the column "comment" to "rcomment" or similar because "comment" is a SQL key word, too.